# create attachment with text and images

Tags: apex, visualforce, attachment, images, outputtext

there is a requirement to show text along with image inside a salesfore Attchment body. currently im using `Attachment record = new Attachment(ParentId = call.Id, Body = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(call.Signature__c), ContentType = 'image/jpeg');
insert record;` but i also need to add some text along with these images. please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the Chatter Feed instead and create a Chatter Post on your traget object with your file and comment.

Chatter posts with files are automatically listet in the attachment section.

Here you can find [Chatter Code Recipes](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Chatter_Code_Recipes)